# Не подключается jmeter при запуске yandex-tank

Tags: jmeter, яндекс-танк

При запуске yandex-tank -c load.yaml терминал выдает следующую ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Использую Jmeter + Yandex Tank.
В Jmeter простой HTTP Request на локальный сервер.
В Yandex Tank такой load.yaml

```
jmeter:
  enabled: true
  package: yandextank.plugins.JMeter
  jmx: /home/dev/work/jm-requests/ammo.jmx
  jmeter_path: /home/dev/programs/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter
  jmeter_ver: 5.4
  buffered_seconds: 0
  ext_log: all
  shutdown_timeout: 10
  variables:
    protocol: http
    host: localhost
    port: 3000
    path: /
    thread_rpm: 10
    loops: 5

overload:
  enabled: true
  package: yandextank.plugins.DataUploader
  token_file: token.txt
  job_name: test
  job_dsc: test description


phantom:
  enabled: false

console:
  enabled: true

telegraf:
  enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на то, что это баг в yandex-tank, стоит [уведомить](https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank/issues) об этом разработчиков/мейнтейнеров

Если вам зачем-то нужны питоновские врапперы для JMeter - можете посмотреть на [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/), он хотя бы [может запускать тесты JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)